# Jquery ajax call to Hello Wiki Rest service in opa

Tags: opa

Can we make ajax call like `http://localhost:8080/_rest_/hello` ?

If I make this ajax call I'm getting response is `null` instead of content of page. But If I run in browser or execute command

`curl http://localhost:8080/_rest_/hello`

it is working fine. please help me thanks.

Comment: How are you making this call? Since `curl` works fine I'd suspect the problems are with the calling side, not with the service response.

Comment: thanks for quick replay.

`$.ajax({
 url: "http://localhost:8080/_rest_/hello",
 type: "POST",
 datatype: "html",
 success: function(resp) {
  $("#response").html(resp);
 }
});`

Comment: And did you check this code against some other (known to be working) REST service?

Answer (score 0):

after some investigations, this is what i found :

```
$.ajax({ url: "http://localhost:8080/_rest_/hello", type: "POST", datatype: "html", success: function(resp) { alert(resp); } });
```

works (notice the alert instead of the html call). So the server gives you a response (as you said, curl succeeds).

What is the content of your server response?

I think you should return a Resource.raw_text("`<some/><html/>`") response for /*rest*/hello because jQuery html function only seems to take valid HTML.

Otherwise, you may do :

```
$('#response').load('http://localhost:8080/_rest/hello');
```